# gdbus type naming for structs

Tags: gdbus

With gdbus  codegen, a struct/object is defined as a complete type in the xml like below

```
<method name="GetInfo">
 <arg direction="out" type="(sib)" name="info"/>
</method>
```

However, if the same struct is used at multiple places, repeating the type definition is a bit painful, especially when the signature changes later on.

```
<method name="GetInfoList">
 <arg direction="out" type="a(sib)" name="info_list"/>
</method>
```

So, is there a way to define an alias or a something for structs that we don't have to maintain the same thing at multiple places? Oh, and using Qt bindings is not an option in this case unfortunately.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there a way to define an alias or a something for structs that we don't have to maintain the same thing at multiple places?

No, there is not. That’s one of the disadvantages of using `gdbus-codegen`. If you want to define a struct for each of the D-Bus types in your API, you need to implement your service/client manually, without `gdbus-codegen`, using functions like [`g_dbus_connection_register_object()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusConnection.html#g-dbus-connection-register-object).